# Python Asyncio and Multithreading

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

I have created a greatly simplified version of an application below that intends to use Python's **asyncio** and **threading** modules. The general structure is as follows:

```
import asyncio
import threading

class Node:
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.loop = loop
        self.tasks = set()

    async def computation(self, x):
        print("Node: computation called with input ", x)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    def schedule_computation(self, x):
        print("Node: schedule_computation called with input ", x)
        task = self.loop.create_task(self.computation(x))
        self.tasks.add(task)

class Router:
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.loop = loop
        self.nodes = {}

    def register_node(self, id):
        self.nodes[id] = Node(self.loop)

    def schedule_computation(self, node_id, x):
        print("Router: schedule_computation called with input ", x)
        self.nodes[node_id].schedule_computation(x)

class Client:
    def __init__(self, router):
        self.router = router
        self.counter = 0

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.counter == 1000000:
                self.router.schedule_computation(1, 5)

            self.counter += 1
    
def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    # construct Router instance and register a node
    router = Router(loop)
    router.register_node(1)

    # construct Client instance
    client = Client(router)

    client_thread = threading.Thread(target=client.run)
    client_thread.start()

    loop.run_forever()

main()
```

In practice the **Node.computation** method is doing some network I/O and thus I'd like to perform said work asynchronously. The **Client.run** method is synchronous and blocking and I'd like to give this function it's own thread to execute in (in fact I'd like the ability to run this method in a separate process if possible).

Upon executing this application we get the following output:

```
Router: schedule_computation called with input  5
Node: schedule_computation called with input  5
```

However, I expect that "Node: computation called with input 5" should print as well because the **Node.schedule_computation** method creates a task to run on loop. In summary, why does it seem that **Node.computation** is never scheduled?

Comment: If node.computation is doing network IO then why do you need threads? Passing an eventloop between threads is asking for trouble, better avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use `loop.call_soon_threadsafe`

##### In general, asyncio isn't thread safe

> Almost all asyncio objects are not thread safe, which is typically not
> a problem unless there is code that works with them from outside of a
> Task or a callback. If there’s a need for such code to call a
> low-level asyncio API, the loop.call_soon_threadsafe() method should
> be used

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading

##### SCHEDULE COMPUTATION

```py
loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.nodes[node_id].schedule_computation,x)
```

##### `Node.computation` runs on main thread

Not sure if you are aware, but even though you can use `call_soon_threadsafe` to initiate a coroutine from another thread. The coroutine always runs in the thread the **loop** was created in. If you want to run coroutines on another thread, then your background thread will need its own `EventLoop` also.